# Using OR into INNER JOIN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dynamic query where I declare 3 different variables like:

```
       DECLARE @JobNoteQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = IIF(@JobNote = '%' , '' , ' INNER JOIN (SELECT ParentGuid FROM JobNotes JN WITH (NOLOCK) 
                            WHERE JN.Note LIKE ''%''+@JobNote+ ''%''
                            GROUP BY ParentGuid) JN ON P.ProjectGuid = JN.ParentGuid');

       DECLARE @ContactQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = IIF(@Contact = '%' , '' , ' LEFT JOIN(SELECT
                        [ProjectKey]
                        FROM [ProjectCustomerContact] AS [pcc]
                            LEFT JOIN [Contact] AS [c] ON [c].[ContactKey] = [pcc].[ContactKey]
                        WHERE [c].[LastName] LIKE ''%''+@LastName+''%'') AS [pcc] ON [pcc].[ProjectKey] = [p].[ProjectKey]')

       DECLARE @CustomerQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = IIF(@Customer = '%' , '' , 'LEFT JOIN(SELECT
                        [ProjectKey]
                        FROM [ProjectCustomer] AS [pc]
                            LEFT JOIN [Customer] AS [c] ON [c].[CustomerKey] = [pc].[CustomerKey]
                        WHERE([c].[Name] LIKE ''%''+@CustName+''%''
                            OR [c].[DBA] LIKE ''%''+@CustName+''%'')) AS [PC] ON [pc].[ProjectKey] = [p].[ProjectKey]')
```

So into select query I use that variables into Joins clause like:

```
  ...INNER JOIN [Region] AS [re] ON [a].[RegionKey] = [re].[RegionKey]
                          '+@JobNoteQuery+'
                          '+@ContactQuery+'
                          '+@CustomerQuery+'
                       WHERE...
```

My question is. If my tree parameters return their values I mean `@JobNoteQuery`, `@ContactQuery` and  `@CustomerQuery`, always return inners and left joins, but value can be null if one of them doesn't have value it just will return empty list, so there is any way to use `OR` clause into `INNER JOINS` ? Like:

```
 ...INNER JOIN [Region] AS [re] ON [a].[RegionKey] = [re].[RegionKey]
          OR
                              '+@JobNoteQuery+'
          OR
                              '+@ContactQuery+'
          OR
                              '+@CustomerQuery+'
                           WHERE...
```

That's not possible? Regards

Comment: This is not possible, unless you use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert your data into temp tables and then you can either start using Unions provided to have same column data types to just get a clubbed result-set of each of the 3 queries. OR you have data in temp tables putting desired join condition be left or inner joins will be a trivial matter at that point.